# Getting return value from setTimeout function call for window.onload

Tags: java, javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Looked all over stacko for this and haven't found anything that works. I'm a bit of a noob to JS so here goes.

I had found this helpful code snippet to find onload page times for my junit webdriver tests -

```
window.onload = function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
   var time = performance.timing.loadEventEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart;
   console.log(time);
   }, 0);
}
```

**My question:** How do I get the "time" variable value to return? I'm executing the script using Java and webdriver's JavascriptExecutor. I need this because sometimes loadEventEnd = 0 since the page hasn't finished loading. If I do an alert(loadEvent - navStart) the value displays properly. I just need to print this value out in my std java output.

**Tried with:**

```
window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(calcTime(), 0);
};

function calcTime() {
   var t = performance.timing.loadEventEnd - performance.timing.navigationStart;
   return t;
};

return calcTime();
```

In this case, I do get the time printed out but **loadEventEnd still returns a 0 (I'm getting t = -1386648543791)**. I would expect calcTime() to be fired when the onload event completes but it seems it doesn't. *What am I missing?*

I've also tried with a callback method but that seems to always return a null value. Probably not doing something right there but I'll avoid this method if I can.

Comment: I think I know the answer to my second question there but that still doesn't solve my main problem. Thanks for those who can help!

Comment: What sort of delay are you expecting? Javascript timers are only good to 1ms resolution, but actual accuracy may only be 2~3ms. Some browsers (e.g. IE) only have 15ms resolution. Time values are based on system settings so absolute accuracy may be rubbish.

Comment: @RobG This delay is only added to make sure loadEventEnd is not 0. Some of my tests don't even encounter the problem. If I add a sleep into the test, values do print out as expected, i.e. no -12312412123, but I don't think sleep is the best way for this.